Poll AD w/o RSAT-AD installed Across Domains
I have read how to poll Active Directory with ADSI.  But, if I'm on another domain and have access to the AD on a different domain to which I have credentials, how do I set up the PS1 script to do this, please?
I know the AD server name, I have a username and password, I know the Base DN, and I know the sAMAccountName I want to parse.  For example:
AD:  ldap://northam.acme.com
User: coyotewe
Pass: IwannaEATthatB1RD
sAMAccountName: 69RoadRunner
I'm new to this realm, so thank you for your patience.
